# How to calculate the distance travelled by a particle using the radius of gyration of its trajectory (represented like a body)?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_gyration) page on Radius of Gyration:

> One can represent a trajectory of a moving point as a body. Then radius of gyration can be used to characterize the typical distance travelled by this point.

So does it mean that assuming the trajectory of any moving point as a body and finding its radius of gyration (about what axis?) can help us find the distance travelled by that body?

I don’t know if I understood it correctly, so please tell me if I am wrong if I use the following as an example: Let's take a ring. Its moment of inertia is $MR^2$ about the axis passing through its center and perpendicular to its plane. This is the same for any particle of mass $M$ located $R$ distance from the same axis. So, according to the two sentences I quoted above, we can represent the trajectory of this point we assumed, ie circular around the axis. This trajectory can be represented as the body, which is the ring in this case, and the radius of gyration, which is $R$ can be used to calculate the distance travelled by the point ($2\pi R$, the length of the body).

Did I comprehend it correctly? If yes, How do we use the radius of gyration to find its distance in any general case? Can we choose any random axis of rotation to calculate the distance?

Comment: I’ve edited the title and the text of this question quite a few times just to better represent my query.